# How to know the USB Device filesystem direction

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, external-hdd

NOTE - Please feel free to correct the title if it is not describing correctly what I am asking here.

What I want to know is, how can I know via Nautilus or a GUI app, the filesystem direction of a pen drive or external usb drive. For example, when I connect a external hard drive called "Mary". In Nautilus or looking at the properties of the device in Nautilus it mentions that is was mounted in `/media/mary` but I want to know if it is /dev/sdb1, /dev/sdc1, etc...

Comment: Nice series of questions @Luis :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it correctly try...

- `dmesg |grep -i 'SCSI device'`

You can also find devices by `id`, `path` and `uuid` with ...

- `ls /dev/disk/by-id`
- `ls /dev/disk/by-path`
- `ls /dev/disk/by-by-uuid`

(in case the 1st one was not the one you are looking for).

Comment: Might be me missing the coffee but I just forgot about doing a "dmesg | tail -n3" after mounting the unit. Thank Rinzwind. But anyway if you have some sort of plugin for Nautilus to also show that info while checking out the properties of the device it would help a little bit more. Also thanks for the ls examples, did not know those.

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in? `Disk Utility` GUI program. Go through the hard drives on the left hand side and it will show you the `Label` and `Mount Point`.